# Acceder a elementos de una matriz mediante aritmetica de punteros

Tags: c, punteros, matrices

¿Cómo puedo acceder a los elementos de una matriz de enteros mediante aritmetica de punteros?

Tengo claro que para acceder a los de un vector es tal que `*(vector+"posicion")` pero para una matriz no se como puedo hacerlo.

Se que se pueden escribir de la forma normal, `matriz[i][j];` pero no con punteros y por mas que he buscado no he encontrado un sitio donde lo expliquen correctamente.

He estado practicando y para ello he hecho un programa super basico que pide al usuario el numero de filas y de columnas que se van a requerir y que rellene la matriz manualmente y luego mostrarla pero me gustaria implementarlo con aritmetica de punteros.

```
 int main() {
 int **matriz;
 int i , filas , columnas;

 printf("\nIntroduce el numero de filas de la matriz: ");
 fflush(stdin);
 scanf("%i",&filas);

 printf("\nIntroduce el numero de columnas de la matriz: ");
 fflush(stdin);
 scanf("%i",&columnas);

 matriz = (int**)malloc(filas*sizeof(int));  //Reservamos el espacio para las filas

 if(matriz == NULL)
 {
     printf("\nError, no se ha podido reservar el espacio...");
     exit(1);
 }

 for(i = 0; i < filas; i++)
 {
     matriz[i] = (int*)malloc(columnas*sizeof(int));    //Reservamos espacio para las columnas
     if(matriz[i] == NULL)
     {
         printf("\nError, no se ha podido reservar el espacio...");
         exit(1);
     }
 }

 IntroducirDatos(matriz , filas , columnas);
 MostrarMatriz(matriz , filas , columnas);

 return 0; }
```

Y las funciones de IntroducirDatos y MostrarMatriz:

```
 void IntroducirDatos(int **matriz , int filas , int columnas) {

   int i, j;

 for (i = 0; i < filas; i++)     //Introducimos datos
 {
     for(j = 0; j < columnas; j++)
     {
         printf("\nIntroduce el valor para la posicion (%i , %i): ", i+1, j+1);
         scanf("%i",&matriz[i][j]);
     }
 }
}
```

Mostrar Matriz

```
 void MostrarMatriz(int **matriz , int filas , int columnas) {

  int i, j;

 printf("\nLa matriz es: \n\n");

 for(i = 0; i < filas; i++)
 {
     for(j = 0; j < columnas; j++)
     {
         printf("|%i ", matriz[i][j]);

     }
     printf("\n");
 } }
```

¿Alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Answer (score 4):

Tal como está tu código, no puedes.

Lo que tienes no es tanto una "matriz" como "un vector de punteros a vectores de `int`". No tienes ninguna información de donde estará `matriz[0][0]` en relación con `matriz[1][0]`.

Echa un vistazo a [este programa de ejemplo](https://ideone.com/6tdEQd) que crea una matriz dinámicamente. Al final se imprimen los distintos punteros que forman la matriz, y verás que no hay una relación directa<sup>1</sup>.

Tal como comentas, si la variable está definida como matriz (y no como punteros de punteros), por ejemplo`int[5][4]`, entonces sí que sabes que, el orden de los elementos será secuencial (`[0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [1, 0] ... [4,3]`) y puedes usar aritmética de punteros. La fórmula para `[i, k]` es

```
i * [número de filas] + k,
```

con el ejemplo de arriba, el elemento [2,3] es

```
matriz + (2 * 4 + 3);
```

---

<sup>1</sup>En medio del bucle he añadido un `malloc` adicional para asegurarme de que `malloc` no devuelva bloques de memoria consecutivos. Pero no es una trampa, porque que `malloc` devuelva bloques de memoria consecutivos es un detalle de implementación y no hay nada en el estándar que asegure que actúa así.

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a echarle un ojo y a implementarlo a ver que tal

Answer (score 0):

pues yo hice esto pero me tira dos advertencias al compilarlo pero lo ejecuta

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define FILA 2
#define COLUMNA 3

void cargar(int *pVI) {
    int vec[FILA][COLUMNA];
    for(int f=0;f<FILA;f++)
    {
        pVI=vec[f];
        for(int c=0;c<COLUMNA;c++)
        {
            printf("Ingrese el elemento f[%i] c[%i]: ",f,c);
            scanf("%i",&pVI[c]);
        }
    }
}

void imprimir(int *pVI) {   
    int vec[FILA][COLUMNA];
    printf("Listado de elementos del vector entero.\n");
    for(int f=0;f<FILA;f++)
    {
        pVI=vec[f];
        for(int c=0;c<COLUMNA;c++)
        {
             printf("%i ",pVI[c]);
        }
         printf("\n");
     }
}

int main() {
     int vecPuntero[FILA][COLUMNA];
     cargar(vecPuntero);
     imprimir(vecPuntero);
     getch();
     return 0;
}
```